# Why `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches` returns `false` in Ubuntu Dark Mode

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, darkmode

I'm using Ubuntu and trying to get the preferred theme of the user, by using `matchMedia` but it always returns `false` for this query.

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches // false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903) in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem between Ubuntu and Chrome. Please check darkmood toggle with Ubuntu and Firefox. Then you can see it’s working without any issue.

So that's why I think it's a problem between Ubuntu and Chrome.

This is a known issue that is traceable through [this page](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903).